# "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous." New column in DataFrame based on comparing on list

Tags: python, pandas

I have looked through many questions with that error but i didn't found anything that can help with my problem.
I've got **DataFrame**:

```
Errors.dtypes
```

*Date        object

Hour         int64

Minute       int64

Second       int64

Machine     object

Position    object

ErrorVal    object

Duration     int64

dtype: object*

and **list of lists**:

```
list_of
```

*[[datetime.date(2019, 1, 27), 'MAS1', 'OBS', '15'],

 [datetime.date(2019, 1, 10), 'MAS1', 'OBS', '21'],

...*

Now, I want to add new column in **Errors** based on **list_of** - when columns 'Date', 'Machine', 'Position', 'ErrorVal' is in **list_of** - the Value of new column 'AboveAv' is True, otherwise False. I tried this:

```
Errors['AboveAv'] = True if ([Errors['Date'],Errors['Machine'],Errors['Position'],Errors['ErrorVal']] in tmp) else False
```

But i got error when i try to run this: *ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*
How i can handle with it? I just want to get new column with information if this row contains in **list_of**

---

Example:
DataFrame **Error**:

```
Date    Hour    Minute  Second  Machine     Position    ErrorVal    Duration
    1   2019-01-12  22  50  30  MAS1    POS     76  94
    2   2019-01-14  3   13  21  MAS1    POS     76  87
    3   2019-01-21  3   14  54  MAS1    POS     14  19
    4   2019-01-22  3   59  57  MAS1    POS     76  87
    5   2019-01-25  4   1   30  MAS1    POS     14  12
    6   2019-01-27  11  15  28  MAS1    POS     76  63
```

**list_of**:

```
[[datetime.date(2019, 1, 21), 'MAS1', 'POS', '14'],
 [datetime.date(2019, 1, 22), 'MAS1', 'POS', '76'],
 [datetime.date(2019, 1, 27), 'MAS1', 'POS', '76']]
```

My new DataFrame:

```
Date    Hour    Minute  Second  Machine     Position    ErrorVal    Duration AboveAv
    1   2019-01-12  22  50  30  MAS1    POS     76  94 False
    2   2019-01-14  3   13  21  MAS1    POS     76  87 False
    3   2019-01-21  3   14  54  MAS1    POS     14  19 True
    4   2019-01-22  3   59  57  MAS1    POS     76  87 True
    5   2019-01-25  4   1   30  MAS1    POS     14  12 False
    6   2019-01-27  11  15  28  MAS1    POS     76  63 True
```

Comment: As the error messages says, you have to append one of `.empty`, `.bool()`, `.item()`, `.any()` or `.all()` to your series. For example, ``..., Errors['ErrorVal']] in tmp).all() else False``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make another DataFrame and merge them.

```
list_of = [[datetime.date(2019, 1, 21), 'MAS1', 'POS', '14'],
          [datetime.date(2019, 1, 22), 'MAS1', 'POS', '76'],
          [datetime.date(2019, 1, 27), 'MAS1', 'POS', '76']]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of, columns=['Date', 'Machine', 'Position', 'ErrorVal'])

df['AboveAv'] = True

Error = pd.merge(Error, df, on=['Date', 'Machine', 'Position', 'ErrorVal'], how='left')
Error.fillna(False)
```

Results

```
         Date  Hour  Minute  Second Machine Position ErrorVal  Duration  \
0  2019-01-12    22      50      30    MAS1      POS       76        94   
1  2019-01-14     3      13      21    MAS1      POS       76        87   
2  2019-01-21     3      14      54    MAS1      POS       14        19   
3  2019-01-22     3      59      57    MAS1      POS       76        87   
4  2019-01-25     4       1      30    MAS1      POS       14        12   
5  2019-01-27    11      15      28    MAS1      POS       76        63   

   AboveAv  
0    False  
1    False  
2     True  
3     True  
4    False  
5     True
```

Make sure the Dtypes are the same or this will not work!!! Check with Error.info and df.info to get more specific results than Error.dtypes and df.dtypes.